# Palindrome (python) input giving than stops

Tags: python

I have a program, but I want it develop it more to:
That it reads a letter from input en print the string to this letter.

So if the input is `b` it will print `aba`. I have now a code that prints a til z and reverse of it... But i Don't know where to start now

```
a_y = ""

for val in range(97, 122):


    a_y += chr(val)


print( a_y + 'z' + a_y[::-1] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to have a loop that will go to the inputed letter

you can do something like this:

```
a_y = input()
res = ""
i = 97
while i < ord(a_y):
    res += chr(i)
    i = i + 1
print( res + a_y + res[::-1] )
```

if input is for example **d**, output will be **abcdcba**

or

```
a_y = ""
end = input()

for val in range(97, 122):
    if val <= ord(end) - 1:
        a_y += chr(val)

print(a_y + end + a_y[::-1])
```

in: d

out: abcdcba

Python **ord()** function returns the Unicode code from a given character.

For example, ord(‘a’) returns the integer 97

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compare `val` with your "start character":

```
a_y = ""
start = 'd'
#start = input("Where to start from: ")

for val in range(97, 122):
    if chr(val) >= start:
        a_y += chr(val)

print(a_y + 'z' + a_y[::-1])
```

Out:

```
defghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfed
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential approach:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

def palindrome(c):
    n = ord(c)-96
    if 1>n or n>len(letters)+1:
        print(f'invalid input "{c}"')
    s = letters[:n]
    return s+s[-2::-1]
```

Example:

```
>>> palindrome('g')
'a'

>>> palindrome('g')
'abcdefgfedcba'

>>> palindrome('?')
invalid input "?"
```